# select by default ScalaI18N messages file

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization

i want to select by default message file for i18n in play framework 2.2 with scala 2.1
**controller**

```
def check = Action { implicit request =>
    val browserLang = request.acceptLanguages(0).code.toString.splitAt(2)._1
    var translated  =Messages("amount")(Lang(browserLang))
    Ok(write(Map("result" -> "success", "lang" -> browserLang,"amount"->translated)))
  }
```

**application.conf**

> application.langs="en,fr,ru"

**there are three messages file**

1. messages.en
2. messages.fr
3. messages.ru

but what if `browserLang` value is be `de`,`pt`,`es` etc..
for those case i want that by default **messages.en** should be selected.

is there any way to set default messages file or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaI18N):

> The default conf/messages file matches all languages.

So you should rename `messages.en` to just `messages` in order to use it as the default. Any keys that are missing from language specific files will then fall back to `conf/messages`.

Comment: Literally just tried it with `conf/messages` and `conf/messages.en`. When I removed the key from `messages.en` I was given the key/value from `messages` instead. So you must be doing something different.

Comment: i deleted my `messages.en` and created `messages` same with keywords `amount=sum` , but not works its giving me `amount`

Comment: Then the problem must be occurring from something you aren't showing, because the method in the documentation clearly works. Also `val browserLang = request.acceptLanguages(0).code.toString.splitAt(2)._1` is grossly unnecessary, as `request.acceptLanguages` is already `Seq[Lang]`.